# Read Csv Datetime / Timestamp format from Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, datetime

I have my CSV data as below and would like to read the csv with correct datetime format using python pandas into a dataframe

input

```
1/1/2022 0:00,5,D1,0
2/15/2022 0:00,10,C1,0
```

output

```
1/1/2022 00:00:00,5,D1,0
2/15/2022 00:00:00,10,C1,0
```

Comment: Can you provide the code with what you have tried so far? One way to do this is to apply a lambda function using datetime or use the pandas built in function to convert a column to datetime. Google is you friend in this, especially when you do not provide code with what you have done and what your exact problems are.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want exactly is unclear, if you just want to add zeros handling the data as string:

```
(pd.read_csv('input.csv', header=None)
   .rename(columns=str)  # trick to be able to use assign with range index
   .assign(**{'0': lambda d: d['0']+':00'})
   .to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=None)
)
```

If you want to handle the dates as datetime:

```
(pd.read_csv('input.csv', header=None, parse_dates=[0])
   .rename(columns=str)
   .assign(**{'0': lambda d: d['0'].dt.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y %H:%M:%S')})
   .to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=None)
)
```

output:

```
1/1/2022 0:00:00,5,D1,0
2/15/2022 0:00:00,10,C1,0
```